# how to get the direction of tga file in java

Tags: java, image, tga

I have read Wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA and I know that the 5-4 bits of the Eighteenth byte of tga file represent the direction of tga file.

So, there is 4 permutations(00,01,10,11) to show us the direction, which direction does each permutation stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the PDF [Truevision TGAª — FILE FORMAT SPECIFICATION — Version 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA#cite_note-3) linked on the Wikipedia page.

> Bits 5 & 4: These bits are used to indicate the order in which
>   pixel data is transferred from the file to the screen.
>   Bit 4 is for left-to-right ordering and bit 5 is for
>   top-to-bottom ordering as shown below.

Comment: Thanks for your explation, it's solved my problem perferctly. Give you an up vote