# Clojure read TGA witout libraries

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop, tga

I want to read TGA file to `BufferedImage`. How I can do it without libraries?

Now there is function:

```
(defn load-image [filename]
  (ImageIO/read (File. filename)))
```

This function read jpeg file successfully, but return `nil` instead of BufferedImage for TGA file.

Comment: You can try to adapt one of the Java solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514035/java-tga-loader to Clojure if you don't want to use a library.

Comment: @AlephAleph It solution of 2009. There are not more fluent solution? And what is library I can use? I try to use Quil, but it is not resolve the problem of reading tga.

Comment: TGA hasn't been included in Java's standard library since 2009 as far as I know, and the format hasn't really changed, so what is wrong with 2009's answers? You can translate the Java code in those answers to Clojure. Would be better to use a library for that to be sure to catch all corner cases though - please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing would be still to use a library, for example [TwelveMonkeys](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys). In your `project.clj` (if you are using Leiningen), add:

```
{:dependencies [... [com.twelvemonkeys.imageio/imageio-tga "3.4.1"]]}
```

Then, in the code:

```
(ImageIO/scanForPlugins)

(defn load-image [filename]
  (ImageIO/read (File. filename)))
```

This will work for valid TGA files.